# Azure Webrole loads old website version after restart

Tags: azure

i run a  azrue webrole (hosts 2 websites + 1 webservice) which was originally uploaded in that mentioned "package".
After the initial upload I published some hotfixes of one of the websites via Web Deploy.

If my azrue role restarts (of whatever reason) the updated sites falls back to the version the role was originally uploaded with.

Is that intended? Is there some way to prevent this? I can't find any information on that topic :(

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you have Azure hooked up to your source control repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my azure role restarts (of whatever reason) the updated sites falls
> back to the version the role was originally uploaded with.
>
> Is that intended?

Yes. Any changes done to the website after the package is published will be rolled back in case Azure decides to tear down the role and put it in another VM. This is because Azure Cloud Services (Web/Worker role) are stateless. However this should not happen when a role restarts (or in other words reboots).

> Is there some way to prevent this?

Unfortunately no. If you want to make your changes persistent, you will have to update the deployment by uploading a new package.