# Windows Azure cloud service asp.net config file changes

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have deployed my asp.net web site using cloud service. I have deployed it by publishing from Visual studio.

problem is every time if i have to make changes to web.config, i have to redeploy from visual studio.

Is there anyway we can directly modify from windows azure? I don't want every time developer should involve in this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining your settings in `web.config` file, you should define them in `Service Configuration File (*.cscfg)`. Then you should be able to change the values from Azure Portal and other means without redeploying your code.

At any cost, **stay away from making web.config changes in the deployed code (using RDP or some other means)**. If for some reason Azure decides to deploy your code in other VM, your changes will be lost. See this thread for more details: [Azure Webrole loads old website version after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254623/azure-webrole-loads-old-website-version-after-restart).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have my setting in web.config file like connection string. I would like to modify this in future. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Other thing you could look into is web.config transformation: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations. That way you can have different connection strings for different environments. However please note that you still won't be able to make the changes once the code is deployed without redeploying the code. HTH.